# How does Set in ruby compare elements?

Tags: ruby, set

I am trying to put custom objects in a set. I tried this:

```
require 'set'

class Person
  include Comparable

  def initialize(name, age)
    @name = name
    @age = age
  end
  attr_accessor :name, :age

  def ==(other)
    @name == other.name
  end
  alias eql? ==
end

a = Person.new("a", 18)
b = Person.new("a", 18)
people = Set[]
people << a
people << b

puts a == b # true
```

It seems that `Set` does not identify same objects with `Object#eql?` or `==` methods:

```
puts people # #<Set: {#<Person:0x00007f9e09843df8 @name="a", @age=18>, #<Person:0x00007f9e09843da8 @name="a", @age=18>}>
```

How does `Set` identify two same objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html):

> `Set` uses `Hash` as storage, so you must note the following points:
>
> - Equality of elements is determined according to `Object#eql?` and `Object#hash`. [...]

That said: If you want two people to be equal when they have the same name, then you must implement `hash` accordingly:

```
def hash
  @name.hash
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Ruby's built-in `Set` stores items in a `Hash`. So for your objects to be treated as the "same" by `Set`, you also need to define a custom `hash` method. Something like this would work:

```
def hash
  @name.hash
end
```

Use `gem which set.rb` to see where the source code for `Set` is stored, and try reading through it. It's clear and well-written.